# GWT SimplePager is not being displayed

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am trying to use SimplePager in my application and set its display to a custom widget that implements HasRows, but the SimplePager is not being displayed.

Here is the UiBinder snippet:

```
<g:LayoutPanel ui:field="mainPanel" styleName="{style.panel}">
    <!-- OTHER LAYERS CONTAINING DATA CONTAINERS (ROWS) -->
    <g:layer left="0%" width="30%" top="0px" height="200px">
        ...
    </g:layer>
    ...
    <!-- LAYER CONTAINING SimplePager -->
    <g:layer left="0px" right="0px" top="400px" height="50px">
        <cv:SimplePager ui:field="pager" />
    </g:layer>
</g:LayoutPanel>
```

Here is the custom widget class:

```
public class MyCustomWidget extends Composite implements HasRows {

    private static final int NUM_ROWS = 3;

    private static MyCustomWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyCustomWidgetUiBinder.class);

    public interface MyCustomWidgetUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyCustomWidget> {
    }

    @UiField LayoutPanel mainPanel;
    @UiField(provided = true) SimplePager pager;

    public MyCustomWidget() {
        // create and initialize SimplePager
        SimplePager.Resources resources = GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
        pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, resources, false, 0, true);
        pager.setDisplay(this);
        pager.setPageSize(NUM_ROWS);
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
    ...
    // HasRows implementations, etc.
}
```

The data is being displayed, pager's hasNextPage() method returns true, but SimplePager is not displayed.  Why?

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM? Could it be hidden behind another _layer_?

Comment: Thomas, thanks. You are absolutely right; it was being blocked by the parent widget, which had a height of 400px (where the pager starts in the child). For some reason, I was sure it had something to do with the inner-workings of the SimplePager :/  Submit your comment as an answer if you like; I'll accept it as the solution.